# Given two points on a sphere, how can I calculate a third point in the same "direction"?

Tags: geometry, spherical-coordinates, spherical-geometry

Given the vector points A and B on a sphere, relative to center, I want to find point C, which would be on the other side of B seen from A, equal in distance and in the same direction. I don't know any fancy math words, so it's hard to explain in text, and even harder to google for answers. Attached is a picture of what I'm trying to find, represented in 2D.
I was thinking it should be possible to identify the "rotation" offset between A and B, and apply that to B to find C, but I don't know how, or if it's possible, or if there are better ways.

[image: points on circle]

Comment: Maybe try this: Find a common perpendicular and rotate about it so that $A$ goes to $B$. Then $B$ should go to $C$.

Comment: This looks like something ["slerp"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp) is usable for, but in this case, you are extrapolating instead of interpolating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r$ be the radius of the sphere.
Let n be the dot product $A.B$  It will be a number between $-r^2$ and $r^2$.
Let $D$ be the point $ nB/r^2$  It will be on the same diameter as $B$ but inside the sphere.
Let $C$ be the point $2D-A$.  It will be on the same straight line in 3space as A and D.

Comment: >"It will be on the same diameter as B but inside the sphere."
What do you mean by this? If has the same diameter, then it cannot be inside the sphere? Or is it offset from the center, having the same diameter but from a different point?

Comment: A diameter is a line through the centre, like the radius is a line between the centre and the surface.  I meant that $BDO$ is a straight line, althoughv$O$ may be between $B$ and $D$ if $A$ and $B$ are far apart.